# Неотображаемая страница 127.0.0.1 для laravel

Tags: php, windows, laravel, localhost, настройки

Установил laravel. Запустил сервер с помощью команды

```
php artisan serve
```

и открыл страницу 127.0.0.1:8000 и в результате получил стартовую страницу с красным логотипом Laravel.

Структура проекта

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

3. Пытался открыть адрес `localhost\laraveltest\laravelproject\public`. В результате получил окно

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите, как отобразить страницу без помощи `php artisan serve`.

**P. S.** Я действовал согласно [Инструкции](http://it-experience.xyz/index.php/ru/notes-ru/web-development-ru/php-ru/94-laravel-setup-openserver-ru) и после ввода laravelsite.loc в адресную строку браузера получал следующий результат

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Уже не в первый раз сталкиваюсь с тем, что перебрасывает в интернет (а не открывает локальный сайт). Подскажите как устранить проблему.

Comment: Вам нужно либо использовать локальный сервер, по типу OpenServer, XAMPP и тп, либо использовать сервер ларавел, который Вы запускаете при помощи `php artisan serve`. Так как в третьем пункте работать не будет (просто добавив вот тот длинный адрес), так как для работы Laravel приложения нужен запущеный PHP сервер.

Comment: @Simon я использую openserver - мне интересен 3-й пункт.

Comment: Я все равно не понял конкретно Вашей проблемы. Для установки/запуска Laravel на OpenServer есть [инструкция](http://it-experience.xyz/index.php/ru/notes-ru/web-development-ru/php-ru/94-laravel-setup-openserver-ru) и не одна.

Comment: Перед адресом сайта добавьте http://

Comment: @Simon спасибо помогло.